# Filling In Region of 3D Plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, 3d

I am trying to fill in the area under this 3D graph, using the idea from [this post](http://pgfplots.net/tikz/examples/fill-space-3d/). Here is a MWE for the function I want to plot under:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{usenames,dvipsnames,table,x11names}{xcolor}
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps,fillbetween}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfdeclarelayer{pre main}
\pgfsetlayers{pre main,main}

\begin{axis}[
zmax=1.25,
view = {45}{45},
grid=minor,
colormap={mycol}{color=(SteelBlue3), color=(SteelBlue3)},
xlabel = $x$,
ylabel = $y$,
zlabel = {$f(x,y)$},
]

\addplot3[
surf,
samples=30,
domain=0:2,
shader=interp,
opacity=0.5,
]
{exp(-(x^2+y^2))};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Now, here is the MWE with the code that *should* shade in the sides:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{usenames,dvipsnames,table,x11names}{xcolor}
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps,fillbetween}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfdeclarelayer{pre main}
\pgfsetlayers{pre main,main}

\begin{axis}[
zmax=1.25,
view = {45}{45},
grid=minor,
colormap={mycol}{color=(SteelBlue3), color=(SteelBlue3)},
xlabel = $x$,
ylabel = $y$,
zlabel = {$f(x,y)$},
]

\begin{pgfonlayer}{pre main}
\addplot3[
surf,
samples=30,
domain=0:2,
shader=interp,
opacity=0.5,
]
{exp(-(x^2+y^2))};
\end{pgfonlayer}

\addplot3 [name path = xline, draw = none] (x,0,0);
 % x is the variable
 % second 0 is the y coordinate of the leftmost part of the graph
 % third 0 is height
\addplot3 [name path = yline, draw = none] (2,y,0);
 % y is the variable
 % first 2 is the x coordinate of the rightmost part of the graph
 % third 0 is height
\addplot3 [name path = xcurve, y domain = 0:0, draw = none] 
    (x, 0, {exp(-x^2)});
 % now instead of height being 0, it is height of function
\addplot3 [name path = ycurve, y domain = 0:0, draw = none]
  (2, x, {exp(-(x^2 + 4))});
 % same idea
\addplot [color = SteelBlue3, opacity = 0.5, draw = none]
  fill between[of = xcurve and xline];
 % fills in x axis
\addplot [color = SteelBlue3, opacity = 0.5, draw = none]
  fill between[of = yline and ycurve, reverse = true];

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

And this is the result:

[image]

Can anyone make any suggestions as to what is going on? It seems when I add multiple functions to the same plot via `\addplot3[]`, everything gets messed up.

Sorry if this seems like a "just fix this for me," but I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

**EDIT**

I now see that for some reason, when adding the new plots to shade in the side, the domain was changed from (0,2) to (-4,4), so setting the domain as you add the plots helps:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{usenames,dvipsnames,table,x11names}{xcolor}
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps,fillbetween}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfdeclarelayer{pre main}
\pgfsetlayers{pre main,main}

\begin{axis}[
zmax=1.25,
view = {45}{45},
grid=minor,
colormap={mycol}{color=(SteelBlue3), color=(SteelBlue3)},
xlabel = $x$,
ylabel = $y$,
zlabel = {$f(x,y)$},
]

\begin{pgfonlayer}{pre main}
\addplot3[
surf,
samples=30,
domain=0:2,
shader=interp,
opacity=0.5,
]
{exp(-(x^2+y^2))};
\end{pgfonlayer}

\addplot3 [name path = xline, draw = none, domain=0:2] (x,0,0);
 % x is the variable
 % second 0 is the y coordinate of the leftmost part of the graph
 % third 0 is height
\addplot3 [name path = yline, draw = none, domain=0:2] (2,y,0);
 % y is the variable
 % first 2 is the x coordinate of the rightmost part of the graph
 % third 0 is height
\addplot3 [name path = xcurve, domain=0:2, y domain = 0:0, draw = none] 
    (x, 0, {exp(-x^2)});
 % now instead of height being 0, it is height of function
\addplot3 [name path = ycurve, domain=0:2, y domain = 0:0, draw = none]
  (2, x, {exp(-(x^2 + 4))});
 % same idea
\addplot [color = SteelBlue3, opacity = 0.5, draw = none]
  fill between[of = xcurve and xline];
 % fills in x axis
\addplot [color = SteelBlue3, opacity = 0.5, draw = none]
  fill between[of = yline and ycurve, reverse = true];

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

And here is the result:

[image]

My question now is, why is the original function shifted up?

**ANOTHER EDIT**

I have figured out a way to get what I want (not including the excellent answers below), but I still have some more concerns. Here is a MWE with a good result:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{usenames,dvipsnames,table,x11names}{xcolor}
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps,fillbetween}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
zmax=1.25,
zmin=0,
view = {45}{45},
grid=minor,
colormap={mycol}{color=(SteelBlue3), color=(SteelBlue3)},
xlabel = $x$,
ylabel = $y$,
zlabel = {$f(x,y)$},
]

\addplot3[
surf,
samples=30,
domain=0:2,
%shader=interp,
opacity=0.5,
]
{exp(-(x^2+y^2))};

\addplot3 [name path = xline, draw = none, domain=0:2] (x,0,0);
 % x is the variable
 % second 0 is the y coordinate of the leftmost part of the graph
 % third 0 is height
\addplot3 [name path = yline, draw = none, domain=0:2] (2,y,0);
 % y is the variable
 % first 2 is the x coordinate of the rightmost part of the graph
 % third 0 is height
\addplot3 [name path = xcurve, domain=0:2, y domain = 0:0, draw = none] 
    (x, 0, {exp(-x^2)});
 % now instead of height being 0, it is height of function
\addplot3 [name path = ycurve, domain=0:2, y domain = 0:0, draw = none]
  (2, x, {exp(-(x^2 + 4))});
 % same idea
\addplot [color = SteelBlue3, opacity = 0.5, draw = none]
  fill between[of = xcurve and xline];
 % fills in x axis
\addplot [color = SteelBlue3, opacity = 0.5, draw = none]
  fill between[of = yline and ycurve, reverse = true];

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Which give this result:

[image]

Now, the issue is the `%shader=interp,` line. When I uncomment this out, this happens:

[image]

So does this command force the graph to shift upwards for some reason? Why does this happen?

Comment: I cannot find a picture of exactly what I need, but I just added another picture which is a closer resemblance to what I need. Pretty much I want to fill in the sides of the graph with the same color as the function.

Answer (score 8):

Something like this?

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{usenames,dvipsnames,table,x11names}{xcolor}
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps,fillbetween}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={f(\x,\y)=exp(-(\x*\x+\y*\y));}]
\pgfdeclarelayer{pre main}
\pgfsetlayers{pre main,main}

\begin{axis}[
zmax=1.25,
view = {45}{45},
grid=minor,
colormap={mycol}{color=(SteelBlue3), color=(SteelBlue3)},
xlabel = $x$,
ylabel = $y$,
zlabel = {$f(x,y)$},
]

\addplot3[
surf,
samples=30,
domain=0:2,
shader=interp,
opacity=0.5,
]
{f(x,y)};

\fill[blue] (0,0,-1) -- plot[variable=\x,domain=0:2] (\x,0,{f(\x,0)}) -- (2,0,-1) --
cycle;
\fill[blue!80] (2,0,-1) -- plot[variable=\y,domain=0:2] (2,\y,{f(2,\y)}) 
-- (2,2,-1) --cycle;

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or, if you do the fills with

```
\fill[SteelBlue3] (0,0,-1) -- plot[variable=\x,domain=0:2] (\x,0,{f(\x,0)}) -- (2,0,-1) --
cycle;
\fill[SteelBlue3] (2,0,-1) -- plot[variable=\y,domain=0:2] (2,\y,{f(2,\y)}) 
-- (2,2,-1) --cycle;
```

you get

[image]

Notice that I added `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}`. If you do not want that, you need to prepend the coordinates with `axis cs:`

```
\fill[SteelBlue3] (axis cs:0,0,-1) -- plot[variable=\x,domain=0:2] (axis cs:\x,0,{f(\x,0)}) -- (axis cs:2,0,-1) --
cycle;
\fill[SteelBlue3] (axis cs:2,0,-1) -- plot[variable=\y,domain=0:2] (axis cs:2,\y,{f(2,\y)}) 
-- (axis cs:2,2,-1) --cycle;
```

Comment: Exactly! I would like the sides to be the same color, but that can obviously be changed very easily.

Comment: @AidenKenny Yes, that's simple, I added something. (In principle one could do it then in one stretch but that does not make the code substantially simpler).